# PowerShell Closure Issue

Tags: wpf, powershell, function, closures

I am learning PowerShell to automate IT works and building a test script to list labels and get its text when I click on.

Here is my PowerShell script but when I click a label, it only print the last label's text.
I am not sure if this is PowerShell closure related issue.
Anyone can help me what is wrong? Thanks for reading.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.text = "test"
$form.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10)
$form.width = "1600"
$form.height = "900"
$form.BackColor = "black"
$form.AutoScroll = $true
$form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$form.WindowState = "Normal"
$form.SizeGripStyle = "Auto"
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $true
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Array = @(
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3",
    "test4",
    "test5",
    "test6",
    "test7",
    "test8",
    "test9",
    "test10",
    "test11",
    "test12",
    "test13",
    "test14",
    "test15"
)

$row = 1
$col = 0
$count = 0
foreach ($itemText in $Array) {
    if ($count -eq 10) {
        $row++
        $col = 0
        $count = 0
    }

    $item = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $item.text = $itemText
    $rowPosition = $row*40
    $colPosition = ($col * 155) +10
    $item.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($colPosition, $rowPosition)
    $col++
    $item.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(150, 30)
    $item.ForeColor = "white"
    $item.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $item.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter

    $item.Add_Click({
        Write-Host "Clicked: $($item.text)"
    })

    $count++
    $form.Controls.Add($item)
}

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()
```

I want to get label's text when I click a label. The current script only print only the last label's text no matter which label I click on.

Comment: Why are you creating a new item inside the loop?

Comment: Just use [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#this) `$this` in the click event to refer to the current label object: `$item.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Clicked: $($this.text)" })`

Comment: @Theo's alternative is definitely the better solution, but, yes, you'd need a closure to capture the then-current `$item` value:  `$item.Add_Click({
        Write-Host "Clicked: $($item.text)"
    }.GetNewClosure())` Note that the resulting script block runs in a dynamic module.

Comment: Thaks Theo and Mklement0. Your answers are the solutions. I didn't know I could use "this"  in PowerShell. Thanks a lot.